# ZF2 return dropdown value, not id in view

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-view

New to ZF2. Pretty sure this is a very basic question as I can easily do it in procedural style, but finding the documentation difficult to work through. Any documentation links gladly received.

I am storing a form dropdown value as an integer, in the db. When I return the results to my view it is returning the integer using:

```
echo $this->escapeHtml($user->system);
```

How do I map this response so that I show the actual value of the dropdown that the user selected in the form?

Comment: I'm assuming that your not using a ORM (`$user->system` is a integer/foreign key rather than `System` object)?

Comment: No, I'm not using ORM, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be via a view helper, although there are other ways.

Create an interface for any entity that is 'aware' of the system, say `SystemAwareInterface`. 
Ensure your user class (or any other class) implements this interface and returns the system id.

```
interface SystemAwareInterface {
   public function getSystemId();
}
```

Create a view helper, i'm assuming a top level namespace of `System` and that you have some kind of service that can load the record from the database by it's identity (lets call it `SystemService` with a method `loadById()`).

```
namespace System\View\Helper;

use System\Entity\SystemAwareInterface;
use System\Service\SystemService;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class System extends AbstractHelper
{
    // Service used to 'load' a system
    protected $systemService;

    public function __construct(SystemService $systemService)
    {
        $this->systemService = $systemService;
    }

    public function __invoke(SystemAwareInterface $entity = null)
    {
        if (0 === func_num_args()) {
            return $this;
        }
        return $this->render($entity);
    }

    public function render(SystemAwareInterface $entity)
    {
        return $this->systemService->loadById($entity->getSystemId());
    }

    public function getName(SystemAwareInterface $entity)
    {
        $system = $this->render($entity);

        return $system->getName();
    }
}
```

Then register the service with the `ViewHelperPluginManager` by adding a factory to `getViewHelperConfig`.

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'System' => function($vpm) {
                $sm = $vpm->getServiceLocator();
                $service = $sm->get('System\Service\SystemService');

                return new View\Helper\Sysytem($service);
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

Now in the view script you can echo the system name using the helper.

```
// echo out the name of the system
echo $this->system()->getName($user);
```

You can also use other view helpers within you new helper; so you could get the `escapeHtml` helper and escape HTML content within the `getName()` method (I'll leave that to you).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, really clearly laid out. I should have been more clear from the start, a have a module called `user`, in which 'system' is just a field in the database, just like 'name' or 'age'. I don't use folders called `/entity/` in my application at the moment. The folder structure of the `user` module is as laid out in the default folder structure generated by the zftool. Would you be able to edit your answer so that I can see it in the context of my `user` module's structure? Sorry, new to this. Thanks!

Comment: @anewvision `entity` is just a folder/namespace with no specific meaning in ZF2 (`model` tends to be another popular one). So you can have the interface anywhere else you like it's just about organizing code in your modules so that If I was to start working on your project I would have a better idea where you domain classes are etc. The same goes for `Service` etc So just go ahead create it or give it another name if you prefer. The only prerequisite is you have the auto-loading setup, I believe ZFTool will take care of this for you anyway.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, I'm new to ZF2 so still learning. But what I can take away from your comment is that the structure is less relevant than I thought and that the namespace is key. Will accept your answer.